# Check if pptx and xlsx files are already open before attempt to open it

Tags: excel, vba

I guess this is a easy one but since I'm very new in VBA I can't figure it out.

I have this peace of code which opens a Power Point presentation and a Excel spreadsheet. `dir_pptx` and `dir_xlsx` are the respective filepaths.

```
Set ObjPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ObjPresentation = ObjPPT.Presentations.Open("" & dir_pptx & "") 
Workbooks.Open Filename:=dir_xlsx
```

My question: how to modify this code for check if the files are already opened and, if they are, don't open it again?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub wbcheck()

For Each B In Application.Workbooks

    If B.name = dir_xlsx Then
        MsgBox B.name & " already open"
        'exit sub or some other handler
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=dir_xlsx
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: would be nice if you provided the powerpoint equivalent as well, since it was asked about as well.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman would be nice except OP would have no opportunity to learn.